# limit django query to current session and pass it to a function view

Tags: django-views, django-forms

So I'm trying to make a calculator of sorts where the user enters some data and then they are presented with a view  that gives them the results they need (printer-friendly format so they can print it).

What I've done so far:

Created a model and a form which they work as intended.

```
**class CalcModel**(models.Model):
    income = models.DecimalField...
    civil_status = models.CharField...
    have_children = models.CharField..

**class CalcForm**(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        **model = Calculate**
        fields = ['income', 'civil...]
```

The view that processes the form and redirects to another view if submitted data is valid:

`data_d = {}`

```
def createcalculation(request):
    form = CalcForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CalcForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
        **data_d['cleaned_data'] = form.cleaned_data**
            form.save()
            return redirect('res-view')
context = {'c_form': form}
return render(request, 'calc/calc.html', context)
```

I think there should be a way to pass the model instance data to the view where the user is redirected but I can't figure it out. So, help is highly appreciated. Right now, I'm 'manually' passing a dictionary containing the data from the form but it doesn't work:

```
def res_ca(request):
    context = data_d
    return render(request, 'calc/res_ca.html', context)
```

I can't seem to figure out how to pass the data for the current session to the **res_ca** view.

The urls if that helps:

```
path('calc', createcalculation, name='calculate'),
path('res/', res_ca, name='res-view'),
```

Comment: I think you don't need session for this. Just use path parameters in your URL and pass the ID of the save instance in the URL. For example , `res/<int:pk_res>`. Then you can retrieve the saved model instance in the view function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @vinkomlacic, I found a way to include the id of the model instance by switching to the render method instead of redirect and it worked like  a charm.

```
    if form.is_valid():
        messages.success(request, f'Successful!')
        item = form.save()
        m_data = Calculate.objects.get(id=item.id)
        context = {'c_data': form.cleaned_data, 'm_data': m_data}
        return render(request, 'calc/res_ca.html', context)
```

This way, the form is saved, I can pass that instance of the model to the next view and it also allows me to add additional context to the template directly from model methods.